# Asking questions about previous answers

Tags: discussion, on-hold

After coming across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17307198/3sum-algorithm-when-integers-are-in-a-given-range), I was intrigued. I recently studied NP problems and was attempting to answer it but eventually realized I couldn't (with anything more than a vague guess). So instead I "favorited" it since I wanted to see the eventual answer. However, I was surprised to find it was instead put On-Hold as being too unclear.

I disagree with this ruling. I think it could use a little bit of rewording but generally it gets the point across. However, I accept this ruling as 5 other people see it that way and attempted to remedy the problem through prescribed channels. I [attempted to edit the questions](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2389954) with a TL:DR that basically amounted to

> Can someone give a layman's explanation of the answer here: 
>      [3SUM algorithm when integers are in a given range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17307198/3sum-algorithm-when-integers-are-in-a-given-range)

I refreshed the page after a few minutes only to find the edit had been rejected.

Was my edit not enough or is the problem that asking for clarification about previous answer is outside of the scope of SO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly do you expect to elaborate on that solution about?  The OP had a question, he found the exact answer.  If there was something *specific* that he asked about the answer, such as, "What did they mean by the term *Foo*?" or "I don't understand how they were able to infer Bar given Baz, why are they able to do that?" then it would be clear what they're asking.

By just saying, "elaborate on this" it could be just about anything that he doesn't understand.  The number of things that you need to cover in order to include every possible thing he might not understand would be beyond the scope of an SO question (as such "too broad" wouldn't be an out of the question close reason either, although I do think "unclear" is a bit better).

As for your edit; it's changing the question.  You may think that it's a useful and related link (and it may very well be, so I would certainly suggest you post it as a comment) however the OP didn't bring it up.  You may think it's more related to what he's having a problem with, but you could be wrong.  Also, even your edit has the same problem as what I described with the OP.  Saying, "Explain this" is too broad for SO, you need to be more specific and clearer about what you want explained about that thing.

Something else that can help a lot in questions along these lines is for the OP to explain what they *do* understand.  This helps readers get a feel for what they already understand, what they think they understand that they really don't, and which concepts they clearly need more clarification on, so while that alone wouldn't necessarily make the question clear enough, it could help quite a bit in improving the question's quality.

Comment: So then it wouldn't be wrong to ask the question myself, provided I can point to what's confusing me about the answer?

Comment: @Daniel Correct, although trying to edit the question to make it much more specific wouldn't be possible; you can't know what the OP wants clarification on.